# Spring Data - NoSuchMethodError JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.setMappingContext()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I wrote a DAL following [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) guide. In particular this is my DALConfig.java configuration file

```
package my.pack;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory;
import org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "my.pack" })
@PropertySource("classpath:dbconnection.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("my.pack.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DALConfig {


    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver_class";  
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";  
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";  
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";  

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_POOL_INITIAL_SIZE = "pool.initialsize";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_POOL_MAX_IDLE = "pool.maxidle";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DAL_CLASSES_PACKAGE = "entities.packages_to_scan";  
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.showsql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";


    @Resource
    private Environment environment;  

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {

        Properties props = new Properties();


        props.put("driverClassName", environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        props.put("url", environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        props.put("username", environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        props.put("password", environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        props.put("initialSize", environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_POOL_INITIAL_SIZE));
        props.put("maxIdle", environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_POOL_MAX_IDLE));

        BasicDataSource bds = null;
        try {
            bds = BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(props);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bds;

    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor()
    {
        PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor b = new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();

        return b;
    }   

    @Bean 
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator(){ 
      return new HibernateExceptionTranslator(); 
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws ClassNotFoundException {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws ClassNotFoundException {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DAL_CLASSES_PACKAGE));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);

        Properties jpaProterties = new Properties();
        jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
        jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProterties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

}
```

This is the Repository I wrote

```
package my.pack.repository;

import my.pack.entity.User;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface IUserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String>{

}
```

Finally this is the test I run

```
package my.pack.tests;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import futureservice.UserService;
import my.pack.DALConfig;
import my.pack.entity.User;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@ContextConfiguration(classes = { DALConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class DALTest {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void testGetUser() {

        User user = null;
        user = userService.findOne("mrossi");
        assertTrue(null != user);

    }
}
```

When I run the test I get the following exception stack and the test fails.

```
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'entityManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.setMappingContext(Lorg/springframework/data/mapping/context/MappingContext;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:62)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1489)
    ... 41 more
```

It seems like the JpaRepositoryFactoryBean misses the [setMappingContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.html?is-external=true#setMappingContext%28org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext%29) method but as you can see from the documentation the method is supported. I'm using the `1.5.1.RELEASE` version of `spring-data-jpa` artifact.

What can be the issue?

Thank you

Comment: Solved by deleting spring-data-commons dependency as stated here jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-337