# Injection of autowired dependencies failed(spring+springmvc+jpa+springdata)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

XML files should be right,because I wrote a simple mvc test demo,it works well.But if I write like this ,Injection of autowired dependencies failed.

applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties"/>
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.user}"></property>  
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>  
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClass}"></property>    
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.jdbcUrl}"></property>    
</bean>


<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"></bean>
    </property> 
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.luoxiao.sssp"></property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="sharedCacheMode" value="ENABLE_SELECTIVE"></property>
</bean>


<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>    
</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>    
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.luoxiao.sssp"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"></jpa:repositories>
```

springDispatcherServlet-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.luoxiao.sssp" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice"/>
</context:component-scan>


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Repository:

```
 @Repository
    public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer>{

    }
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Transactional
    public Page<Employee> getPage(int pageNo,int pageSize){
        PageRequest pageable = new PageRequest(pageNo-1, pageSize);
        return employeeRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }       
}
```

Handler:

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeHandler {

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/emps")
    public String list(@RequestParam(value="pageNo",required = false,defaultValue="1")String pageNoStr,Map<String,Object>map){
        int pageNo = 1;
        try{
            Integer.parseInt(pageNoStr);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Page<Employee> page = employeeService.getPage(pageNo, 5);
            map.put("page", page);
        }
        return "emp/list";

}
```

}
Exception:

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.luoxiao.sssp.repository.EmployeeRepository com.luoxiao.sssp.service.EmployeeService.employeeRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'entityManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.setMappingContext(Lorg/springframework/data/mapping/context/MappingContext;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.luoxiao.sssp.repository.EmployeeRepository com.luoxiao.sssp.service.EmployeeService.employeeRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'entityManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.setMappingContext(Lorg/springframework/data/mapping/context/MappingContext;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Check if this helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087527/spring-data-nosuchmethoderror-jparepositoryfactorybean-setmappingcontext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer this,

[Spring Data - NoSuchMethodError JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.setMappingContext()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087527/spring-data-nosuchmethoderror-jparepositoryfactorybean-setmappingcontext)

Its common issue where dependencies are in conflict states.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by deleting spring-data-commons dependency.Thank you so much, TechBreak!